# Making Windows Boot Loader the default instead of Grub 2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

So basically before Ubuntu 13.04 I was running 12.10. I had Windows Boot Loader the default. If I chose to boot to Ubuntu, it would go into grub, but grub was set to 0 seconds so it would basically skip grub and just go straight into ubuntu.

Now, after upgrading, Grub is back. I used EasyBCD to get everything correct on the Windows side but now I cannot figure out for my life how to get grub to appear AFTER Windows Boot Loader.

I tried to go into the grub config and change the default to 4, which is the line where Windows is on. All that did was highlight Windows on start instead of going straight into the Windows Boot Loader first.

I also tried to use Boot Repair to change "OS to boot to by default" to Windows, which also did not work.

Can someone **please** help me get it back to how it was? I've been trying for hours.